# How to compile a copy for each supported culture in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization, culture

On a .Net project, that can support few languages (using resx files), how can I compile a copy of the app for each language?

Currently I have a static hard-coded member that contains the culture:

```
static CultureInfo CULTURE = new CultureInfo("en-Us");
```

this member is sent to my resource manager:

```
LangResourceMgr.Culture = CULTURE;
```

Now, for each culture i manually change the member and re-compile.

```
static CultureInfo CULTURE = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

Is there a way, using visual studio to build all at one time, creating multiple files?

Comment: Well... that's not a good way of supporting multiple languages. Why don't you just make the culture a setting of your application?

Comment: Ok, So the CULTURE line just moves to another location - settings. Still hard coded. how can I compile all cultures at once?

Comment: You could use satellite assemblies